# G2 as algebra of endomorphisms preserving a trilinear form

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am trying to find some literature or papers about the topic in the title. I've read multiple times that the Lie-Algebra G2 can be described in such a way, but I've yet to find some good, understandable source for this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: See [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwipupzVq__LAhUMKpoKHfmDANEQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sciencedirect.com%2Fscience%2Farticle%2Fpii%2F0021869387901736&usg=AFQjCNG7-qTq5Og-6TU7BqU_eUfCvLuaVw&sig2=OceO7SdVjqElLfKC6_uMqw) for a reference.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check "Octonions, Jordan Algebras and Exceptional Groups", but it is quite possible you misunderstood something : $G_2$ is connected to $3$-Pfister forms, which are bilinear (it is also possible that there is an interpretation involving $3$-linear forms that I've never heard of, though).

Comment: There is the $7$-dimensional Dickson alternating *trilinear* form, also called "$G_2$-form", whose monomials in $(x_1,\ldots ,x_7)$ are given by $f=x_1x_2x_3+x_1x_3x_6+x_1x_4x_7+x_2x_3x_4+x_5x_6x_7$.

Comment: There seems to be some kind of trilinear form that G2 preserves, since I've read that it can be viewed upon as a subgroup of SO(7) preserving this said form. Could this be the form that I have read about?